react-draggable issue on mobile devices
I have an issue with react-draggable library, when on mobile or tablet devices onClick from children are not propagated. Anyone knows which might be the reason?
<Draggable onStart={handleDragStart} onDrag={handleDrag} onStop={handleDragStop}>
  <div
    className={!cartWidgetCollapsed ? styles.widgetContainer : styles.widgetContainerCollapsed}>
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', pointerEvents: isDragging ? 'none' : 'auto' }}>
      {cartWidgetCollapsed ? (
        <div className={styles.widgetCartContainerCollapsed} onClick={toggleOpenCart}>
          <CartIcon disabled={isDragging} />
          <div className={styles.widgetTogglerExpanded} onClick={toggleCollapse}>
            <img draggable={false} src={expand} alt={ALT_CONSTANTS.ACTION_ICON} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className={styles.widgetTogglerCollapsed} onClick={toggleCollapse}>
            <img draggable={false} src={collapse} alt={ALT_CONSTANTS.ACTION_ICON} />
          </div>
          <div
            className={styles.widgetCartContainer}
            {...(!isDragging && { onClick: toggleOpenCart })}>
            <SuffixSelect
              disabled={isDragging}
              isLoading={isFetchingSites}
              icon={locationPin}
              dropdownStyle={{ visibility: isDragging ? 'hidden' : 'initial' }}
              listOptions={sites}
              value={selectedSite?.code}
              onChange={changeSiteHandler}
              customStyles={{
                borderRadius: '12px',
                marginBottom: '7px',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                borderColor: 'var(--primary-100)',
                backgroundColor: 'var(--primary-100)',
                pointerEvents: isDragging ? 'none' : 'auto',
              }}
            />

            <div className={styles.widgetAmount}>
              <p>{UtilService.numberToDollar(cartAmount)}</p>
              <p className={styles.widgetCart}>
                <Icon isEmbedded disabled={isDragging} />
                <span>{'Click ->'}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</Draggable>

From the code you can see onClick={toggleOpenCart} and onClick={toggleCollapse}. Both are propagated only on PCs.

Logs show anything?

@TheMaster nothing
